# Computer not booting - no OEM logo - only lights are on

Tags: bios, uefi

I have a laptop with UEFI BIOS. I accidentally set it to fastboot and also disabled the default windows boot option. Now, the laptop turns on without any display and without the option to enter the BIOS settings. How to solve this without disconnecting the battery?

Comment: I think I also deleted the Windows Boot options from the BIOS.

Comment: Hello and welcome here. Please add information about your laptop model and brand so people can help you.

Comment: Laptop Model: IBall Excellence OHD.

Comment: Right now, as I power up, the power LED glows for 2 seconds, followed by NumLock LED. After that, nothing works, no display. Also, the OEM splash screen displayed earlier does not show now.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think there's any quick solution besides resetting the battery for the BIOS to go back to factory. Have you tried using an external monitor on the HDMI port and see if the BIOS is accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Fast boot usually skips some ram tests. Try to remove a ram module and then boot the computer. Failing that you may have to disassemble the laptop and remove the cmos battery or attempt a bios recovery from usb or hdd file.